# Loading a USDZ file with a standard behavior crashes my app

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

Using iOS 16.1 Xcode 14.1

Used reality converter to change my *.usd model into a *.usdz
Used reality composer to add a standard jiggle behavior and now trying to load it into my project.

But as it does so it crashes with this message...

```
2022-12-10 20:33:07.457940+0100 LAC[6905:4041138] -[USKObjectPath UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281a5c560
2022-12-10 20:33:07.458127+0100 LAC[6905:4041138] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[USKObjectPath UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281a5c560'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186e59e88 0x1801878d8 0x186fce84c 0x186e6ffa0 0x186ed8350 0x195271bfc 0x1952710c4 0x1952783ac 0x195271238 0x1f8f9cf5c 0x1f8cd20f0 0x1f8cd2708 0x1f8cd23dc 0x1f8cd18a8 0x1f8d5225c 0x1f8f9000c 0x1f8f9026c 0x1f8f9026c 0x1f8f9093c 0x1f8f9128c 0x1f8f8eddc 0x1f8f92308 0x1f8f8efb8 0x201738af4 0x1f8f8dfac 0x1f8f8df48 0x1f8f247ec 0x1f8f338a8 0x1f8d3891c 0x1026945a8 0x10269605c 0x10269e10c 0x10269ee68 0x1026abcbc 0x1d3eafdf8 0x1d3eafb98)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[USKObjectPath UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281a5c560'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Tried doing so with no behavior, it works! so the *.usdz file without the behavior is good... its clearly the standard behavior?

I should add that I can select the *.usdz file in xcode and it displays the content no problem, so the file it would appear isn't corrupted? I just missed something in the code when I import it.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this? These few lines will crash it.. the loadModel

```
let nextAsset = "rook12"

do {
    let asset2Load = try Entity.loadModel(named:nextAsset)
} catch {
    print("error \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [load(named:in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/load(named:in:)) type method. It always saves the day.

*Xcode 14.2 RC*.

```
let nextAsset = "qwerty.usdz"
    
do {
    let asset2Load = try Entity.load(named: nextAsset)
    print(asset2Load)
    
    let me = asset2Load.findEntity(named: "Mesh0")?.children[0] as? ModelEntity
    me?.model?.materials[0] = UnlitMaterial(color: .orange)
    
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    asset2Load.setParent(anchor)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

`.usdz` model's components' hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6599590/andy-jazz thanks for your suggestion; but it won't work bc I cannot get past that first line; when it loads the model it does some sort of validation I guess and crashes-

Comment: @user3069232, If it's so, then you have problems with `.usdz` model itself (possibly your model is corrupted). I ran this code in Xcode 14.2 RC.

Comment: I am also getting same issue while running the app by using USDZ file getting crash with same error. Can you please help me how to resolve this @AndyJazz